# Radioactive radiation from granite and marble surfaces

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

Do granite and marble surfaces that are common in houses nowadays emit harmful radiation?

Comment: https://www.epa.gov/radiation/granite-countertops-and-radiation

Comment: You can take it for granted to all natural substances (and a large fraction of processed one) have some mild degree of radioactivity. It is always a matter of amount. We live in an environment with a mean exposure of around 1 mrem per day from natural and artificial sources, so that is the bench mark against which particular (whole body) exposures should be judged.

Comment: On an interesting note manufacturers know how to produce any kind of drinking alcohol from oil or other synthetic. They could make whiskey, rum, vodka or anything but they know they would ruin the market. So they made it illegal to produce product this way and they test by measuring the amount of radiation. Because oil has lost its radiation they only allow alcohol with radiation to be sold for consumption.

Comment: Bill, that is very interesting. It seems  there is no need to fear from granite or marble surfaces in homes.

Comment: dmckee, I think you should post your comment as an answer so I can mark it accordingly. What you mentioned makes sense.